# nodeJS image size increase/decrease and crop

Tags: node.js

I am using node gm module for image manipulation like below

```
 gm(req.files.file.path)
    .rotate('white', parseFloat(body.angle))
    .scale(body.mW * 1, body.mH * 1)
    .crop(body.mW_W * 1, body.mH_W * 1, body.x * 1, body.y * 1)
    .resize(parseInt(body.w), parseInt(body.h), "!")
    .quality(1)
    .setFormat("png")
    .write(small, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('Done!');
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('error occurred');
    }
});
```

The actual dimensions might be different but the width and height I am feeding to `scale` (also tried `resize`) method could be higher or lesser actual dimensions. Because of this I am getting image as it is with resized to final `body.w, body.h` dimensions.How can I resize an image without bothering about original dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, if anyone using `jquery guillotine` or similar library to select portion of image crop at server, please use below code

```
 var newW = body.imageWidth * body.scale, newH = body.imageHeight * body.scale;
 gm(req.files.file.path)
    .rotate('white', body.angle)
    .resize(newW, newH, '!')
    .crop(body.w, body.h, body.x, body.y).write(path, function(err){

    });
```